# Print result XSSFCell.setCellFormula()

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

when I run the folowwing code, he just print the first Formula but not the second, I don't know why.

```
for(int r = 13;r<15;r++){
        row = sheet.getRow(r);
        cell = row.createCell(i, XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
        cell.setCellStyle(StyleOfThisCell.getTotalStyle(workbook));
        String formule = "SUM(C"+(row.getRowNum()+1)+":"+CellReference.convertNumToColString(row.getCell(i-1).getColumnIndex())+(row.getRowNum()+1)+")";
        cell.setCellFormula(formule);
    }
```

Could you please help me and let me know if I forget something to have my result.

Thanks

I just have seen a problem : 
I open my excel with libreOffice. If I open it with microsoft excel, I can't see both of my totals. But if I click on activate modification, both of my totals appears. I don't understand.

Comment: What is 'i' in the third line of your code?

Comment: the position of the cell.
In my case, the position of the cell Total at the end of my line of days to calcul the numbers of days

Comment: I can't see any code [evaluating the formulas before you save](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) - did you forget that step?

Comment: It works !!!! It workssssss !!! you're a genius !

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple !

After have put a cell with a formule, we need to code an evaluator :

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

Thanks Gagravarr !!